# Converting List to DataTable

Tags: c#, json, datatable

This is basically a follow up to a previous question I posted of Deserializing JSON to a DataTable. Well the process is nearly finished, this is the code:

```
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic d = JObject.Parse(result);
            }


           var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);




 public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }
        object[] values = new object[props.Count];
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return table;
    }


  public class Record
    {
        public int StatusID { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string StatusDate { get; set; }
        public string WorkedBy { get; set; }
        public string ContactedOn { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public  List<Record> Record { get; set; }


    }
```

Now, the deserialization is working perfectly, but I cannot convert to DataTable. I am using the ToDataTable extension I found in SO, and this snippet is supposed to turn my list into a DataTable:

```
RootObject.Record.ToDataTable<Record>();
```

Now of course I cannot do this, since Record is not a static member, but if I make it static, like this:

```
 public static List<Record> record { get; set; }
```

and change the ToDataTable extension call to

```
 RootObject.record.ToDataTable<Record>();
```

It breaks the conversion from JSON to List. Using breakpoints if I verify the "root" var its null and has no data, so when it tries to turn it into a  DataTable the whole thing crashes since it only has null values.

Comment: Yes I do. If I call it without it being static I get this: 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `RootObject` contains the `Record` property so you need to use it to create the `DataTable` like this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
root.Record.ToDataTable<Record>();
```

What you have tried is to access it as a static memeber of the `RootObject` class which is in this context wrong becasue the deserialization creates already an instance of `RootObject`. You now just have to use the `Record` property that you want to convert to a `DataTable`.

---

That's why I think it's not always good to use the `var` keyword. Sometimes you forget or oversee what type it is. If you wrote:

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

you might have found the solution by yourself.

Comment: Ooooh!! I see, thanks a lot that seemed to work (at least the program didn't blow in my face now)

Comment: Thanks for the throughout explanation, leaned something good. Will definitely apply it like that, thanks a million it all worked.